Trying two ways to reference a token on Sepolia
I am working on mirroring an arbitrage swap on Sepolia to test my contracts.
It was suggested in a previous answer to use use DevOpsTools to interact with the contract.
address xTokenAddress = DevOpsTools.get_most_recent_deployment("XToken", block.chainid);
XToken xToken1 = XToken(xTokenAddress);
console.log("DevOpsTools xTokenAddress:", xTokenAddress);

Initially I used
XToken xToken2 = XToken(vm.envAddress("XToken"));//address from deployed contract on Sepolia

After running
function test_executeArbitrage()public{
   address xTokenAddress = DevOpsTools.get_most_recent_deployment("XToken", block.chainid);
   XToken xToken1 = XToken(xTokenAddress);
   console.log("DevOpsTools xTokenAddress:", xTokenAddress);

   console.log("vm.envAddress(\"XToken\"):", vm.envAddress("XToken"));
   XToken xToken2 = XToken(vm.envAddress("XToken"));//address from deployed contract on Sepolia
   if(xToken1 == xToken2){
      console.log("xToken1 == xToken2");
   }
   else{
      console.log("xToken1 != xToken2");
   }
}

I get the following output
Traces:
  [40310350] ArbitrageTest::test_executeArbitrage()
    ├─ [0] VM::readDir("./broadcast", 3) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] [("", "/home/user/Documents/xtoken-list/broadcast/Arbitrage.s.sol", 1, true, false), ("", "/home/user/Documents/
    ├─ [0] VM::keyExistsJson("<JSON file>", "$.transactions[2]") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] false
    
    ... 1000+ lines from DevOpsTools ...

    │   └─ ← [Return] <file>
    ├─ [0] VM::parseJsonUint("<stringified JSON>", ".timestamp") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 1730696772 [1.73e9]
    ├─ [0] console::log("DevOpsTools xTokenAddress:", 0xe34Ac9E64fb1db3b3bb30988462014Cb525de040) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] VM::envAddress("XToken") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] <env var value>
    ├─ [0] console::log("vm.envAddress(\"XToken\"):", 0xe34Ac9E64fb1db3b3bb30988462014Cb525de040) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] VM::envAddress("XToken") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] <env var value>
    ├─ [0] console::log("xToken1 == xToken2") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    └─ ← [Stop] 

Suite result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 2.14s (408.97ms CPU time)

It appears that I can get a reference to the contract on Sepolia two different ways.
I would prefer not to use DevOpsTools because it totally litters the terminal.
Any comments about a preferred way and why?

I’d suggested to use foundry-devops library, particularly if you want to get the latest deployed contract instance for any network if you’re deploying multiple contract instances while doing progressive testing or so.
But, if you want to hardcoded deployed address(es) from .env file, then your initial method for referencing the address using vm.envAddress("XToken") would be fine.
NOTE: To decrease the number of lines getting printed in your terminal while executing the tests, you can try using the lesser verbosity levels like -vvv or -vv, if currently you’re using it upto 5 levels i.e., -vvvvv.
You can refer to the Foundry docs regarding the usage of verbosity level, that says:

Verbosity levels:

2: Print logs for all tests
3: Print execution traces for failing tests
4: Print execution traces for all tests, and setup traces for failing tests
5: Print execution and setup traces for all tests


